# Is there a way to get exact location of query match in elastic search documents

Tags: python, elasticsearch, subquery, elastic-stack

I have stored some HTML pages in ElasticSearch, now I want to match an input string with all the strings present in those HTML and get the exact location of the match. So far I have written this query:

```
 "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": queryText,
      "default_field": "html"
    }
  }
```

This returns the whole document where the match is found. Is there a way to get the exact location of the match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage the [Highlight feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/highlighting.html), like this:

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": queryText,
      "default_field": "html"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "html": {}
    }
  }
}
```